# Types of Android Login Method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, authentication

Based on a research that I have made on Android login, I have found out that for Android to have a login feature, it requires a web service.

Android sends login credential to web service and will only determine whether a user's credential is valid based on the return result of the web service.

As I am currently a junior developer, I am wonder what are the other approach that modern developers used in handling Android login feature? Do they use Google Firebase, or they used web service to handle the login as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition they can use social media login such as Facebook,google...etc as another option to let user login to app if user dont like to use app web services...to add this features you have to know about [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) because its used by those giant tech above then go and read their docs they explain all with the details of details....also for web services check out this tut [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) also you can read this [A Massive Guide to Building a RESTful API for Your Mobile App](https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-to-build-restful-api-mobile-app)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what resources you have access to. I work for a variety of enterprises and find that it is not uncommon for them to use google firebase as a login/authentication component, but many of them create their own web service to handle user login. Some use Single Sign On services like Okta.